# Необходимо в файле удалить слова с двойными буквами

Tags: c

Задание: В текстовом файле удалить все слова с двойными буквами (например: медленно, странный, программирование и т.п.).
Заранее большое спасибо
Пробовал сделать получилось только с одной стройкой, а как сделать со всеми строками ума не приложу

```
int main(void) 
{   
FILE *fi;
fi=fopen("text.txt","r+");

char str[500]; 
int i, count = 0, size; 
char g = ' ';
char* ptr; 

for (i=0; i<500; i++) str[i]= ' ';
fgets(str,sizeof(str),fi);
ptr = strtok(str, " "); 

while(ptr) 
{  
    size = strlen(ptr); 
    for ( i = 0; i < size - 1; ++i) 
        if(ptr[i] == ptr[i+1]) 
        { 
            for (i = 0; i < size; ++i)
            {
            ptr[i] = g; 
            }
            break; 
        } 
        ptr = strtok(0, " "); 
} 
fclose(fi);
FILE* fd = fopen("text.txt", "wb");
for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++){
    fprintf(fi,"%c",str[i]);
}
fclose(fd);
}
```

Comment: Хм.. Применить тот же код к остальным строкам?

Comment: Логично, вот только как это сделать )

Comment: Дополнил вопрос, если разбираетесь помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Писать результат в другой файл. Потом переименовать его.

Comment: Требуется обрабатывать русский текст? Или, может быть, только латиницу? В какой кодировке (если русский текст)?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <unistd.h>

void    ft_putchar(char c)
{
    write(1, &c, 1);
}

int     ft_check_symb(char *str, char *symbol)
{
    while(str < symbol)
    {
        if(*str == *symbol)
            return (0);
        str++;
    }
    return (1);
}

void    ft_union(char **av)
{
    int string;
    int symb;

    string = 0;
    while(string < 2)
    {
        symb = 0;
        while(av[string][symb])
        {
            if(ft_check_symb(av[0], &av[string][symb]))
                ft_putchar(av[string][symb]);
            symb++;
        }
        string++;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if(argc == 3)
        ft_union(&argv[1]);
    write(1, "\n", 1);
    return (0);
}
```

Это моя реализация функции , которая принимает 2 строки и выводит все символы без повторов.Повторы сравниваются в функции:

```
int     ft_check_symb(char *str, char *symbol)
```

функция принимает полную строку и указатель на память символа на котором мы остановились, далее мы создаем цикл , в котором условие будет выполняться пока у нас не встретиться символ либо указатель str не станет указывать на память символа на котором мы остановились.Думаю можете переделать под себя, логика понятна.

Полный код для определения:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int     check_repeat(char *str)
{
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while(str[i])
    {
        if(str[i] == str[i + 1])
            return (0);
        i++;
    }
    return (1);
}

void    repeats(char **ag)
{
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while(ag[i])
    {
        if(check_repeat(ag[i]))
            printf("%s ", ag[i]);
        i++;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    repeats(&argv[1]);
    return (0);
}
```

для его работы , необходимо записать весь файл в 2-ух мерный массив(записывать с помощью split(скинул в комментариях)).
Функция определена как ft_split(char *, char(разделяющий символ в вашем случае это пробел)).

Более точный вызов функции:

```
char **tmp;

tmp = ft_split(arr, ' ');
```

Пример работы кода:
[image: Работа алгоритма]

Comment: для разбиения файла на строки: Запишите весь файл в массив и с помощью функции split , разделяете слова по пробелу.функция split возвращает указатель на указатель(в простонародье двумерный массив)Далее просто идете по ячейкам этого двумерного массива и парусите слова , если функци check_symb вернула 0 , то вы просто пропускаете это слово.

Comment: Я написал эту функцию(split), тк ее нет в языке си, делюсь с вами: https://github.com/tyuuki21/libft/blob/master/ft_split.c

Comment: в функции , которая ищет повторы вы просто меняете условие основного цикла "string < 2" на "arr[i]", arr - это двумерный массив.

Comment: конкретно для вашего алгоритма вы парсите символ и следующий за ним символ , если он равен вашему , то вы просто пропускаете слово.